# PHP protect directory from direct URL access

Tags: php, apache, security, .htaccess, authentication

I have an ADMIN script.

```
admin/index.php
```

All activity is done through this `index.php` file. 
 Users are logging in before gaining access to the program functionality.
`$_SESSION['user_authenticated']` is created and set to **true**.

```
admin/template/..
```

This folder contains `images`, `css`, `javascript` files. 
They are used only within this ADMIN. (in the backend only)

**The question:**

I need all the content from `admin/template/..` directory to be protected against **direct access**.
It should be available only to authenticated users.

I guess there has to be a `.htaccess` redirecting requests to `check_session_auth_variable.php`, which looks if `$_SESSION['user_authenticated']` is **true** or **false** and **redirects to requested file** or **throws a 404 error**?

*I know that the best option would be to place the directory outside of the web root, but in my case I need to keep the directory structure as is, without modification.*

Comment: Best answer is: **dont' do it.** Give open access to css/js files, protect php files, protect subdirs using `deny from all` and thats it. LOT of popular wordpress blogs have open access to `/wp_admin/*` ([example](http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gizmodo.co.uk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1)) and it's really ok as long as there is no security issue in your php files

Comment: Why would it be bad when someone unauthorized would see any of the images, stylesheets, or JavaScript files? Is there any sensitive data in it?

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski Thank you for the answer. And thank you for the idea to use `deny from all`, if necessary I think it can be used along with `allow from IP`.

Comment: @Gumbo No there is no sensitive data in those files, so for now I will probably go with the simple way as Peter Szymkowski proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**admin/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !check_auth.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* check_auth.php?file=$0 [QSA,L] # pass everything thru php
```

**admin/check_auth.php:**

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
if($_SESSION['user_authenticated']) {
    // please mind you need to add extra security checks here (see comments below)
    readfile($file); // if it's php include it. you may need to extend this code
}else{
   // bad auth error
}
```

Comment: Just a note on this process: It's usually not a good idea to do this on sites that will have high traffic as the overhead of spinning up a PHP thread to process a simple file read is waaaaaaay more than letting Apache/IIS/etc serve the content statically. So just bear that in mind if you're going to be doing this on a high traffic admin panel. IMO when it comes to graphics/JS files for an admin panel, security through obscurity is usually sufficient. Turn off the directory listing for the admin folder (which you should do anyway). There shouldn't be anything "secure" in JS/HTML code anyway

Comment: @Brian Agree, this is bad idea for high-traffic admin panel. There is few thing we can always do: 1. restrict admin panel to few ips. 2. clean js code from vulnerabity 3. change admin panel dir name to something like "/admin6234123312" :]

Comment: Just another note, obviously you're going to want to do some additional security checks before just `readfile()`ing the file out. Since PHP/Apache is likely to have access to way more files on the server, that makes the script open to exploitation to access files the user shouldn't be able to. If someone hijacks an admin session they could technically use that file to read any file on your site in plaintext (usernames, passwords, database information, etc). Provided they knew the file path of course.

Comment: I meant moreso on the PHP side. For example if I were to request the .htaccess file in that directory the PHP script would likely have permission to read it and it would output the file contents to me via readfile. Same would go for any configuration files. Additionally I could utilize ../ in my request path to traverse outside the admin root directory and get any files on the site.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski No, it’s not. `check_auth.php?file=/etc/hosts` is still possible.

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing this (and have been considering these comments for some time now) and I want to make sure I haven't missed anything (this needs to be mildly secure without displaying the ugly http basic auth) 1. The admin will be accessed by a select few, so traffic intensity will not be an issue 2. we will do a php `include()` to execute any php before sending it to the browser and 3. we will only display files RELATIVE to the directory of check_auth.php so that  no one can randomly just read out /etc/adsfasf. Is this a secure implementation of above?Have I forgotten anything?

Comment: also! you need to scan for '..' so they can't climb the directory hierarchy!

Comment: ... the best answer really is "don't do it" -- you need to worry about sending the right mime type for images/js/css/anything else AND make sure the headers are telling the browser to cache the right things AND you have to do `$path = getcwd();
chdir(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
include($file_name);
chdir($path);` to make sure the directories are correct. And after that? you get a polluted namespace because you can't effectively sandbox the script (or if you can i.e. shell_exec, you don't have access to `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_FILES`...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here is my answer - and it's true that the best answer is 'no'. But the images/js/css are relatively important in development (before becoming public when live) and client previews dictate that we can't do an IP based apache rule. So, the rule (from above, slightly amended) is

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude the public and error directories from authentication
RewriteRule ^(public|error)($|/) - [L]

# Perform authentication via php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !auth.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* auth.php?requested_file=$0 [QSA,L]
```

(because I needed a few subdirectories where content was indeed public, read: the images/css/js used on the login page)

and the relevant php is as follows; for

```
        if($authenticated){
            if($extension == 'php'){    

                call_user_func(function(){

                    $file_name = func_get_arg(0);

                    $path = getcwd();
                    chdir(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
                    return include($file_name);
                    chdir($path);

                }, $file_name);

            } else {

                //set cache headers so the browsers don't have to refresh all the
                // static content
                header_remove('X-Powered-By');
                header_remove('Transfer-Encoding');
                header_remove('Cache-Control');
                header_remove('Pragma');
                header_remove('Expires');
                //header('Expires:');

                header('Content-type: '.$mime_type);
                readfile($file_name);
            }
        }
```

what this does is executes php using `call_user_func()` to stop namespace pollution, `include()` to execute PHP, and `chdir()` to make sure the script gets a proper current working directory.

That's the 'easy' part; the content headers and mime type have to be 'guessed' (I used finfo for the mime types, but it has a bug as at 2013, and this only serves to exacerbate the issue) but even apache can't do that 100% properly...

Then delete the cache control headers for images otherwise you'll not only be often as php pages as well...

suffice to say; you only need to do this if you have thick pipes and a lot of cpu cycles you don't need...

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this

```
$redi_ext = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$php_verify = strpos($redi_ext, ".php");
if($php_verify !== false){ header('location: PAGE_NOT_FOUND_URL'); }
```