# Open a password protected directory on the server using Java for Android

Tags: java, php, android, .htaccess

I'm creating an android app which has a network connection to a server
and I have  a PHP file that connects to my database on the server to updates some values and a JSON PHP file.

I need to add these files to a password protected directory on the server for more security but if I do that I can't access them from my app anymore.

Is there a way to access that directory using android java, so only the app 
"with the correct password" can access the php files.

I have tried to prevent the access using the "deny from all" in `.htaccess` file but it will prevent anybody from accessing these files

**In short**: I want only my app to access my PHP files.

Comment: This might help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421087/php-protect-directory-from-direct-url-access)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a simple app for you, you can include a password in the link (GET parameter), but that is not secure at all.

If you actually want it to be secure, you will have to use POST data, and your server must have a SSL certificate so that they communicate without anyone seeing the password.

Also you should deny direct access to the folder containing the above files using a .htaccess file.

You can be find more details and tutorials either in stack overflow or google.

Comment: so there is no way to access a file from the mobile app only

Comment: No, just to lock it so it can be accessed only from your app.